# Respuesta a llamada AJAX siempre da error si se indica dataType: "json" y si se quita el success no interpreta los datos

Tags: php, ajax, html5, json, mysqli

En un formulario HTML cuando en un input se teclea un DNI de una persona, al perder el foco se activa una función de JavaScript ("buscar") para mostrar sus datos personales, se invoca a un módulo php mediante AJAX que funciona correctamente y retorna los datos formateados json.

Si en la llamada a AJAX se indica `dataType` la respuesta siempre retorna error (`alert("Error data en linea 87 a 9x.....")`), y si se quita, la respuesta no detecta los datos devueltos de forma correcta.

Pongo alertas y muestro los datos que van informados correctamente, pero al preguntar si existe el DNI para llevar datos a los inputs de detalle se va por el else y da la alerta *'El SOCIO no existe, ¡Crealo! !!'*.

Estoy probando con un DNI que existe y los datos devueltos son correctos: se corresponden con los existentes en la Base de datos.

Los datos devueltos y mostrados en la `alert('HTML/_retorna_data : ' + data + ' !!' )` son los siguientes:

```json
{"existe":"SI",
"nombre":"Miguel",
"ape1":"Probando",
"ape2":"Datos",
"direccion":"FUENTE EL FRESNO",
"telefono":"666777888"}
```

Esta es la parte del código del formulario:

CÓDIGO HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>PROBANDO PARA SENDATOLEDO</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    
    <div class="cargando row">       
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Cargando...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
      <div class="formulario row">
      <!-- INICIA LA COLUMNA -->
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
          <center><h1>DNI</h1></center>
    
          <form>
            <!--Campo Documento-->
            <div class="mb-2">
              <label for="doc">Dni</label></br>
              <input type="text" name="doc" class="form-control" id="doc" onblur="buscar();">
            </div>
            <!--Campo Nombre-->
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre"> 
            </div>
            <!--Campo Dirección-->
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="dir">Dirección </label>
                <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" id="dir">
            </div>
            <!--Campo Teléfono-->
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="tel">Teléfono </label>
                <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel">
            </div>
            <!--Botones-->
            <center>
              <input type="button" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_enviar" onclick="guardar();">
              <input type="button" value="CANCELAR" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn_cancelar" onclick="limpiar();">
            </center>
          </form>
          <div class="resultados"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La parte Javascript de las funciones invocadas es la siguiente:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.cargando').hide();
          });  
    
    function buscar()
      {    
        var parametros = 
        {
          "buscar": "1",
          "doc" : $("#doc").val()
        };
        $.ajax(
        {
          type:'post',
          data: parametros,
          url:'00_codigos_php.php',
          //dataType: "json",
          
          beforeSend: function() 
          {
            $('.formulario').hide();
            $('.cargando').show();
            
          }, 
          error: function()
          {alert("Error data en linea 87 a 9x.....");},
          
          complete: function() 
          {
            $('.formulario').show();
            $('.cargando').hide();
           
          },
   
          success: function (data) 
          {
            alert('HTML/_retorna_data : ' + data + ' !!' );
            
            if(data.existe =="SI")
                {alert('HTLM_data_existe : ' + data.existe + ' !!' );  
                $("#nombre").data.nombre;
                $("#dir").data.dom_pobla;
                $("#tel").data.tfno_mov;
                }
            else
                {
                alert('HTML_El SOCIO no existe, ¡Crealo! !!' ); 
                $(".resultados").html(data);
                }     
           //limpiar();
          } 
        })
      }
    
    function limpiar()
      {
        $("#doc").val("");
        $("#nombre").val("");
        $("#dir").val("");
        $("#tel").val("");
      }
    
    function guardar()
      {
        var parametros = 
        {
          "guardar": "1",
          "doc" : $("#doc").val(),
          "nombre" : $("#nombre").val(),
          "tel" : $("#tel").val(),
          "dir" : $("#dir").val()
        };
        $.ajax(
        {
          data:  parametros,
          url:   '00_codigos_php.php',
          type:  'post',
          beforeSend: function() 
          {
            $('.formulario').hide();
            $('.cargando').show();
            
          }, 
          error: function()
          {alert("Error");},
          complete: function() 
          {
            $('.formulario').show();
            $('.cargando').hide();
           
          },
          success: function (mensaje) 
          {$('.resultados').html(mensaje);}
        }) 
        limpiar();
      }
    </script>
```

[image: Resultado del console.log]

La parte del código del PHP de la función "buscar" 00_codigo_php.php es esta:

```php
   ?php
    include "conexion.php"; 
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection fallida: " . $con->connect_error);}  
    
    $doc = $_POST['doc'];
    $funcion1 = $_POST['buscar'];
    $funcion2 = $_POST['guardar'];
  
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
         {       
            $doc = $_POST['doc'];
            $data = array();
            $data['existe'] = "0";
            //CONSULTAR
            $consulta="
            SELECT * FROM PRU_Maesocios
            WHERE dni = '$doc' 
            ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$consulta) 
                or die ("Problemas con la consulta: " . mysqli_error($con));  
            $rowSocio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $data['existe'] = "SI"; 
            $data['nombre'] = $rowSocio['nombre'];
            $data['ape1'] = $rowSocio['ape1'];
            $data['ape2'] = $rowSocio['ape2'];
            $data['direccion'] = $rowSocio['dom_pobla'];
            $data['telefono'] = $rowSocio['tfno_mov'];
          
            /*echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert('PHP_buscar_despues de select=> 00_codigos_php.php :  $doc :  $data ###');
                   </script>";   */
    
            sleep(1);
            echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        }
```

Comment: Tu php debe incluir `header('Content-type: application/json');` antes de emitir cualquier salida.

Comment: Gracias Sal. si pongo ese código en PHP, en el retorno captura 'ERROR'.

Comment: Revisa el log de php y agrega a la pregunta lo esencial de `00_codigos_php.php`.

Comment: Sal, he añadido la parte del PHP, pero podrás comprobar en el console.log, que la respuesta es correcta con los datos enviados..

Comment: Por cierto: ¿por qué tu JS de Bootstrap es de la 4.0.0 y del CSS de Bootstrap la 3.3.7? ¿Por qué importás dos veces jQuery, en diferentes versiones? Y por último, importá los JS _antes de cerrar el `body`, no en el `head`_.

Comment: Gracias padaleina. he realizado los cambios siguientes: <body>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
Y sigo con el mismo problema. Supongo no es problema de versiones de librerías...

Comment: Sigo con losmismos problemas, en algún momento ha funcionado, pro sigue dando error al activa la linea  ´dataType: 'json',´`

Comment: **padaleina** Gracias por tu aportación, era parte de la solución. Está funcionando correctamente si la página está en estado "Borrador", si subo la página al estado "Publicada" la respuesta siempre se comporta por "ERROR".  
¿Por donde o a quien puedo preguntar o donde se puede comprobar quien está provocando este comportamiento?

Answer (score 0):

Cual es el código de retorno en el módulo de php? Al parecer la respuesta del módulo es en formato texto. Lo que tendrías que hacer es transformar la respuesta en formato string a json:

const obj = JSON.parse('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

Esto lo aplicarías quitando el dataType.

Comment: El módulo php retorna la siguiente respuesta:  

sleep(1); 
echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: Esto parece más una pregunta. Cuando tengas la suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios para pedir información.

Comment: Mateo, efectivamente hice una pregunta, con tu comentario no respondes a mi duda que, no se resolver. Gracias, si puedes ayudarme te lo agradecería..

Comment: @Econed Mateo nada más se equivocó, quiso decir "esto parece más un comentario". Se lo decía a Marco, no a vos :)